# Google Conversation Assistant Sunset

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant

I have a good project based on actions on google precisely in dialogflow es will the project I created disappear along with the sunset of actiobs on google? and how to avoid it?

I've been looking for countermeasure info but haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

- Conversational Action with dialog flow  is no longer supported with Google Assistant. You can find more information in this regard [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset/faq#can_i_still_build_conversational_actions_with_dialogflow).
- You can see if any of the migration paths is covering your use case . For eg: For back and forth dialog with users via chatbots we have some alternative products like [Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs) and [Dialogflow EX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs).